# How to use an external file with dict value while rendering Jinja template

Tags: python, jinja2

I am going to be using a file as a data source for **account_details** below. Can anyone please tell me how I can make it work? This is a combination of doit and Jinja2. Basically I am trying to pass dict value in file as input,

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
from pathlib import Path

account_details = [
    {'alias': 'MEMBER1', 'region': 'us-east-1', 'member_account_id': '0000000000', 'ccs_mem_account_id': '0000000000'},
    {'alias': 'MEMBER2', 'region': 'us-east-2', 'member_account_id': '0000000000', 'ccs_mem_account_id': '0000000000'}
]

def task_render():
    """ "Render jinja2 templates.
    Yields:
        Render task for each jinja2 template file.
    """
    cwd = Path(".")
    environment = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader(cwd))
    j2_templates = cwd.glob("*.j2")

    def render_template(template_path):
        """Render template.
        Args:
            template_path: Path to jinja2 template file
        """
        template = environment.get_template(str(template_path))
        with open(f"{template_path.stem}", "w") as output_file:
            output_file.write(template.render(data=account_details))

    for j2_template in j2_templates:
        target = f"_{j2_template.stem}"
        yield {
            "name": target,
            "actions": [
                (
                    render_template,
                    [j2_template],
                    {},
                ),
            ],
            "file_dep": [j2_template],
            "targets": [target],
            "clean": True,
        }               render_template,
                    [j2_template],
                    {},
                ),
            ],
            "file_dep": [j2_template],
            "targets": [target],
            "clean": True,
        }
```

Comment: How about using [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)? _(especially the [json.load](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) method)_

Comment: Thanks for sharing. but still I am stuck not able to pass the data to template.render(). Not sure whether it even takes data passed as argument.

Comment: 1. The code you're provided here is erroneous. task_render yields a syntactical incorrect dict. 2. You don't have provided a minimal working example. You're saying that you're using doit. It is unclear what you mean, I can only guess you mean https://pydoit.org/ which is not a common library. Also how your iterator/generator function is used is completely missing -- So 3. Please edit your question and make it possible for the reviewers to help you. Either by including doit code or better by removing doit code if your problem lies more in how to use jinja2.